# Should I be worried because my Raspberry booted quickly in first time I powered it with flashed raspbian in SD card?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

am new with pi , and i just burned one and am afraid if did something silly again cost me another one

i use sd card class 10 and flashed raspbian by Disk Image Writer on my ubuntu.

when my last pi fried i bought new sd card to try if it's because of him or not , so i use the same sd card i tried in the dead pi , Is that is dangerous or maybe cause any faults ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as long as the SD Card is fresh with a new install of NOOBs or the OS of your choice, you should be fine.